# Loop to iterate given time by 1 hour

Tags: bash

I am splitting a 24-hour timeframe API call into an hourly one. I need to create time intervals like 00:00-01:00, 01:00-02:00, ... and assign them to variables start_time and stop_time to be used in the call.

Got this so far:

```
date=$'20210825'

for i in {0..23}
    
    start_time=$(date -d $date "+ "$i"hour" +%s)"000"
    stop_time=$(date -d $date "+ "$i+1"hour" +%s)"000"
    
    echo $start_time
    echo $stop_time
    
    API call happens here inside for loop
```

But it complains about syntax error. Any ideas on how to correctly increment the variables?

Comment: Where do you get syntax errors? You obviously lack the `do` and `done` statements but showing where exactly things go wrong would help rule out some possible other problems (a common one is using `sh` instead of `bash`).

Comment: Consider using https://shellcheck.com to check out your script and find/fix syntax errors.

Comment: consider updating the question with the expected output (`start_time` and `stop_time`) and the full/complete syntax error message(s) you're receiving

Comment: For the follow up question: do you want to change the interval in minutes? Like 00:00 - 00:30 - 01:00 - etc?

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit. Post a new question (with a link to this one, probably) if you have a new question. (The text is still available in the [revision history.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68939373/revisions))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following `date` format:

```
start_time=$(date -d "${date} + ${i} hour" +%s)"000"
```

---

The `+1` can be done using the `$((...))` syntax:

```
"${date} + $((i + 1)) hour"
```

---

So the script becomes:

```sh
date=$'20210825'

for i in {0..23}; do
    
    start_time=$(date -d "${date} + ${i} hour" +%s)"000"
    stop_time=$(date -d "${date} + $((i + 1)) hour" +%s)"000"
    
    echo $start_time
    echo $stop_time
    echo -e
done
```

---

#### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY7BCsMgEETvfsUilkRCgrEUCqXfUmy16KHZoPYkfrs1IRAKpXOYWQbeMncVbClaRXNljRRyFGd5agh5ogcHboIkhkEe8wU0EqhaLUTl4y26V6XaBYZeA2VpOTN0wJLLYPHtKXSHwKkQgm4gzv@4tnU1Rs5/0quZh0Vg@4Kvcvu@d70hGidTygc)

---

Output:

```
1629849600000
1629853200000

1629853200000
1629856800000

1629856800000
1629860400000

1629860400000
1629864000000

1629864000000
1629867600000

1629867600000
1629871200000

1629871200000
1629874800000

1629874800000
1629878400000

1629878400000
1629882000000

1629882000000
1629885600000

1629885600000
1629889200000

1629889200000
1629892800000

1629892800000
1629896400000

1629896400000
1629900000000

1629900000000
1629903600000

1629903600000
1629907200000

1629907200000
1629910800000

1629910800000
1629914400000

1629914400000
1629918000000

1629918000000
1629921600000

1629921600000
1629925200000

1629925200000
1629928800000

1629928800000
1629932400000

1629932400000
1629936000000
```

Comment: This did the trick! I see I left out a few syntax parts for the loop as well, but overall this works elegantly :)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did in the past for similar scenario:

```
year='2021'
month='08'
date='25'
for i in {0..23}
do
    end=$(($i + 1))
    start_time=$(date -v ${year}y -v ${month}m -v${date}d -v${i}H -v0M -v0S +%s)"000"
    stop_time=$(date -v ${year}y -v ${month}m -v${date}d -v${end}H -v0M -v0S +%s)"000"

    echo $start_time
    echo $stop_time
done
```

- Added **do** / **done** statements to for loop
- Used **-v** to adjust each date part

Comment: The `-v` options look like you are on BSD, whereas the OP seems to be on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the time intervals are within the same day, there is no need to call `date` multiple times. Just call it once to get the baseline, then add to that.

```sh
baseline=$(date -d 2021-08-25 +%s)

for((i=0; i<24*3600; i += 3600)); do
    start_time=$((baseline+i))"000"
    stop_time=$((baseline+i+3600))"000"
    printf '%s\n' "$start_time" "$stop_time"
done
```

I'm wondering if the stop time shouldn't be the start time plus 3599.999, though.

This "C-style" `for` loop syntax is a Bash extension, and not portable to POSIX `sh` etc.